# JavaScript отобразить массив строк в массив объектов

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs

Пусть имеется компонент React с состоянием:

```
this.state =
{
  term: "", // to store what we passing as a value to our input
  items: [] // store every value which we passing to our todo list
};
```

Я хочу отобразить массив строк items в массив объектов { text: "Запись", done: false }. Пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
let todos = this.state.items.map((item) => {{ text: item, done: false}});
```

Но интерпретатор считает, что здесь text и done это метки. Как решить задачу? Массив таких объектов я хочу передать в компонент, реализующий список.

Answer (score 4):

Здесь ошибка в функции `map`. функция принимает элемент массива и должнa вернуть измененный элемент. У вас же констукция `=> {{ text: item, done: false}}` в принципе не валидна.

или заменить внешние скобки на круглые

```
=> ({ text: item, done: false})
```

или "открыть" стрелочный оператор в функцию с телом.

```
=> {return { text: item, done: false}}
```